# How are parameters bound to second position in pipeline?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to understand how parameters are bound to the second position of a cmdlet, within a pipeline.

Tried with Select-String [1]. It has `-Path`, which accepts pipeline input at position 1 (second position). These work:

```
sls "the-pattern" "the-file.txt"
"the-file.txt" | sls "the-pattern" -path {$_}
```

But this doesn't:

```
"the-file.txt" | sls "the-pattern"
```

In this latter case, I expect "the-file.txt" to be bound as the 2nd argument to `sls`.

**How do parameter binding work after the first position, in Powershell?**

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.3#parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help?view=powershell-7.3) provides crucial information to answer your question:

```bash
Get-Help Select-String -Parameter LiteralPath, Path, Pattern, InputObject |
    Select-Object Name, Position, PipelineInput, Aliases
```

We can see the following:

```
name        position pipelineInput         aliases
----        -------- -------------         -------
LiteralPath named    True (ByPropertyName) PSPath, LP
Path        1        True (ByPropertyName) none
InputObject named    True (ByValue)        none
Pattern     0        False                 none
```

Both `-LiteralPath` and `-Path` are bound [ByPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#valuefrompipelinebypropertyname-argument) whereas `-InputObject` is bound [ByValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#valuefrompipeline-argument).

Knowing this we can assume the following, in the first example:

```bash
Select-String "the-pattern" "the-file.txt"
```

- `"the-pattern"` is bound positionally to `-Pattern`.
- `"the-file.txt"` is bound positionally to `-Path`.

In the second example:

```bash
"the-file.txt" | Select-String "the-pattern" -Path { $_ }
```

- `"the-pattern"` is bound positionally to `-Pattern`.
- `"the-file.txt"` is bound **by name** to `-Path` [**using a delay-bind scriptblock**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters).

In third example, which works perfectly fine except it doesn't work how you expected it to work:

```bash
"the-file.txt" | Select-String "the-pattern"
```

- `"the-file.txt"` is bound to `-InputObject` **by ValueFromPipeline**.
- `"the-pattern"` is bound positionally to `-Pattern`.

You can see this is true by simply trying `"the-file.txt" | Select-String "the-file"`.

As for things you didn't try, [`Trace-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/trace-command?view=powershell-7.3) helps a lot understanding how parameters are bound. This particular case is hard to understand at first because `Select-String` will always bind `-InputObject` from pipeline, no matter what (this happens because the parameter type is [`PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0)) and most likely has internal logic determining when it should treat the object coming from pipeline as a file and read from it's path.

Here is an example of what I mean, using a temporary file. `$tmp` should be bound to `-LiteralPath` because the object has the `.PSPath` property but instead it gets bound to `-InputObject`:

```bash
$tmp = New-TemporaryFile
$tmp = Get-Item $tmp.FullName
Trace-Command ParameterBinding { $tmp | Select-String .+  } -PSHost
```

**Output**

```
BIND NAMED cmd line args [Select-String]
BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Select-String]
    BIND arg [.+] to parameter [Pattern]        
        Binding collection parameter Pattern: argument type [String], parameter type [System.String[]], collection type Array, element type [System.String], no coerceElementType
        Creating array with element type [System.String] and 1 elements
        Argument type String is not IList, treating this as scalar
        Adding scalar element of type String to array position 0
        BIND arg [System.String[]] to param [Pattern] SUCCESSFUL
MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Select-String]
CALLING BeginProcessing
BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Select-String]
    PIPELINE object TYPE = [null]
    RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
    Parameter [InputObject] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION
    BIND arg [] to parameter [InputObject]
        BIND arg [] to param [InputObject] SUCCESSFUL
MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Select-String]
CALLING ProcessRecord
CALLING EndProcessing
```

---

For anyone wondering, here is the logic in the source code where it checks if the input object is a [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-7.0) instance: [**MatchString.cs#L1502-L1509**](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/MatchString.cs#L1502-L1509)

Comment: I can't find an example of a cmdlet that takes 2 pipeline parameters by value. But, in general, assuming that Select-String were like that, would the piped string be bound to the 2nd parameter, in the case of: `"file.txt" | sls "pattern"`

I'm trying to understand the general case of how a pipeline argument would be bound to a 2nd parameter if the first parameter is given an explicit value.

Comment: @Dess you most likely won't find a cmdlet taking 2 parameters by `ValueFromPipeline` in the same ParameterSet, that would be quite odd thing to do. 2 parameters bound by `ValueFromPiplineByPropertyName` is quite common, my previous answer demonstrated one example (`[pscustomobject]@{ Group = 'common'; Verb = 'Add' } | Get-Verb`). `"file.txt" | sls "pattern"` -> `file.txt` is bound to `-InputObject` as explained in my answer, not sure what you mean by "the 2nd parameter"

Comment: "you most likely won't find a cmdlet taking 2 parameters by ValueFromPipeline in the same ParameterSet". I'm satisfied by this answer. I was trying to understand how such mechanism would work, assuming (as I did) that it was possible. But, since that's not a thing, then there's no more to do. Thank you.

Comment: @Dess __it is possible__ but is also quite odd thing to do and would become a terrible UX

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon get-verb in ps7 has 2 byvalue parameters, verb and group

Comment: @js2010 yes and it's a terrible UX